# Macro Deleting All Items

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that I'm trying to ONLY delete a single picture, however it's deleting all my items on the sheet (Checkboxes, TextBoxes, Buttons etc.).

I should also mention there are two images on the sheet, however I want it to only delete the second picture.

```
Private Sub DeletePictures()

    Dim shape As Excel.shape

    For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shape.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Just find out the name of the shape and no need to loop: `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape1").Delete`

Comment: Try adding this to the code and using debug to determine the shapes you want to retain `Debug.Print CStr(shape.Type) + " " + shape.Name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to find the name of your shape.

In Excel 2010:

- Select your picture and click the "Format" ribbon.
- In the "Arrange" section click the "Selection Pane" icon.  The names of all the shapes on the sheet should appear on the right of the sheet with your selection highlighted.

Next update your code to only work on the named shape:

```
Private Sub DeletePictures()

    Dim shape As Excel.shape

    For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shape.Name = "Picture 1" Then
            shape.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

If you want to delete all pictures you can check the shape type:

`If shape.Type = 13 Then` or `If shape.Type = msoPicture Then`

A full list of shape types:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432678(v=office.12).aspx

**Edit:**

Had a moment there.... obviously once you know the name of the shape there's no need to loop through all the shapes on the sheet (Thanks @CallumDA for pointing the obvious out in your comment). :)
`ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1").Delete` - is all the code you need.

Comment: This answered my question perfectly, since there are new images being inserted frequently I will use the `If shape.Type = 13 Then` statement. However, I did notice that once I insert a new image and run the macro again, this image isn't being deleted... I should mention that this new image being inserted is from a `Selection Window`. Are you aware of any issues with this method? Maybe I should use `LinkedImages` too?

Comment: Confirmed, I tested it with deleting of type 11 (Linked Image) and it worked!